# Print CSS background image

Tags: css, internet-explorer, printing, background-image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Print background image in IE without enable “Print background colors and images”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197278/print-background-image-in-ie-without-enable-print-background-colors-and-images)

Is there an hack to print CSS background-image w/o asking to user to check if the IE Print Background image is checked or not?

I researched all morning and the only option I found is to have a print.css file. Is it possible to do within the original style sheet w/o adding additional stylesheets in the head?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what kind of background you have, but if it is non-repeating, one simple option would be to place an absolute positioned image under your other elements instead of specifying a background-image for the page.

Comment: #topImage{margin-top:10px; width:949px; height:429px; background:url("mainImage.jpg") no-repeat top;}

Comment: That's a little ambiguous, give this a try.
http://cssdesk.com/FskN4

Answer (score 0):

you could add `@media print { print styles in here }` at the bottom of your stylesheet and this should do the job for you.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and still it doesn't work. Here is my CSS code #topImage{margin-top:10px; width:949px; height:429px; background:url("mainImage.jpg") no-repeat top;}

Comment: No, it shouldn't. The preference overrides page authors' desires to use up enormous amounts of ink/toner.